# rails globalization "undefined method for translates" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined, globalization

after watching rails cast: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6CMY3mUv90
i tried myself to globalize my rails project but i am getting "undefiend method for translates" error

```
gem 'globalize'
```

i did a bundle install in my bash terminal and also did bundle updates sucessfully

then i added  "translates: title, :content" like below:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :admin
has_many :comments

rails_admin do
    edit do
        field :title
        field :content, :ck_editor
        field :link_title
        field :link
        field :admin
    end
end

translates: title, :content
```

end

then i added

```
class TranslatePosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    Post.create_translation_table!({
      :title => :string,
      :text => :text
    }, {
      :migrate_data => true
    })
   end

  def self.down
    Post.drop_translation_table! :migrate_data => true
  end
end
```

AND i did rake db:migrate

but i am getting the erro still. any idea why it is not working?

Comment: Have you tried to force a specific version in your gemfile like this: `gem 'globalize', '~> 5.0.0'`

Comment: thanks for your reply! Yes, i did. but it was not working even though i tried several versions in the gemfile.. do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score -2):

Two things to be checked;
- It seems that you missed colon in the translated attributes `:title`.
- Restart rails server may be helpful.

Comment: This is not an answer. You should have used the "comment" function.